# How to resolve javascript error in UC Browser

Tags: javascript, error-handling, syntax-error, uc-browser, contentful-api

I made a dummy shopping-cart site after watching a tutorial on it, the site functions well on all browsers I've tested it on except UC Browser pc version. It keeps sending back two errors in the console log;

1. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function            contentful.browser.min.js:1
2. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier                app.js:27

I don`t know how to get pass these errors.
This is the link to the dummy site: https://fojo-comfy-house.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0):

async/await is ES6 syntax. It's possible that UC browser for desktop doesn't support ES6 (I couldn't find any information on whether that's the case though)